# Python 3.7.3, win10, No module named '_curses'

Tags: python, curses

It's my first time trying to use curses, after successfully installing it with `python -m pip install windows-curses`, (re-runing this code gives `Requirement already satisfied: windows-curses in c:\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (2.1.0)`).

I ran the sample code:

```
import curses
import time

screen = curses.initscr()
screen.clear()
time.sleep(3)
```

And got the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\Cris\Desktop\test.py in 
----> 1 import curses
      2 import time
      3 screen = curses.initscr()
      4 screen.clear()
      5 time.sleep(3)

~\Anaconda3\lib\curses\__init__.py in 
     11 """
     12 
---> 13 from _curses import *
     14 import os as _os
     15 import sys as _sys

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_curses'
```

which says curses is not installed...?

I ran this using VSC's Python Interactive tab (`shift+enter`),  simply running it through VSC gives:

```
LINES value must be >= 2 and <= 132: got 13682
initscr(): Unable to create SP
```

Comment: For anaconda, use conda, not pip, to install additional packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python for Windows doesn't come with curses.go to [curses](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses), download the version of curses that corresponds to your Windows and version of Python, and then pip install the whl file with python